# Saving multiple data one at a time in database in Android

Tags: android

I want to save multiple files to my database one by one.

And what happen here using my codes is this:

[image]

**What I want to happen is like this one:**

[image]

here is my code:

```
//Arraylist for getting the multiple brand code
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();

     for (int j=0; j<checkSelected.length; j++) {
         if(checkSelected[j]==true) {
             String values = BrandListAdapter.mListItems.get(j);
             //content.add(values);
             Cursor rSubBrand = databaseHandler.getReport_SubBrandCode(values);
             String SubBrandCode = rSubBrand.getString(rSubBrand.getColumnIndex(Constants.SUBBRAND_CODE));
             content.add(SubBrandCode);

             //Casting and conversion for SubBrand Code
             String subBrand = content.toString();

             //SAVE SUBBRAND
             databaseHandler.SaveSubBrand(new Cons_iReport (ReportCode, subBrand));

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), subBrand, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }                                  
}
```

Comment: content.clear() before adding new SubBrandCode.

Comment: @Tarun, do you know how to remove the '[ ]' in the saved data? (e.g. [AC001]) All I want to save is the AC001 only

Comment: `StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
   result.append( content[i] );
}
String mynewstring = result.toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mistakes:

1. `content.add(SubBrandCode);`
2. do you know how to remove the '[ ]' in the saved data? (e.g. [AC001]) All I want to save is the AC001 only.

### Solutions:

1. Call `clear()` method of ArrayList before adding new values into it.
2. Its giving you [AC001] as you are `subBrand` by doing `content.toString();`. Don't convert it to string, instead use `content.getString(position)` and it will give you String value.

Comment: do you know how to remove the '[ ]' in the saved data? (e.g. [AC001]) All I want to save is the AC001 only